# How to store multiple pages data in the last page using C#, ASP.Net

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to save a application which has multiple pages. But I dont want to save it in each step. Rather I want to see the summary of multiple pages in the last page and then only I want to save the application. Can you please help on the same.

Thanks,
vsari

Comment: Capture this data into Session variable or Cookies and use on last page.

Comment: You can achieve the same scenario by putting all the controls in one page, but in different div according to  the their group, and then button to Previous Next or do [Accordion style][1] to display the content/controls one after another.
In the last div you can put your submit button to submit the whole content.


  [1]: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Answer (score 0):

Use the ASP.NET Wizard Control and save data from each wizard step into Session state, then retrieve from Session at the end:

[Walkthrough: Advanced Use of the ASP.NET Wizard Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7dyf6b5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)